# What are the exact requirements of the Convention badge?

Tags: support, badges

I was checking the badges page when I came across the [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) badge. Its description states:

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.

I am bit confused by the description. By ‘score of 2’, does it mean that each of the 10 posts needs to have a score of exactly 2 or will the badge be awarded if an user has 10 posts each with score >2?

Comment: The most recent person to earn it has 12 posts with the majority being well over 2, so it's safe to assume it's the easier of the two.